# "Até o nosso encontro no dia tal..." comigo ou com eu?

Tags: pronomes, concordância

Ao enfatizar as pessoas que estarão no encontro, sendo uma delas o próprio interlocutor, qual forma é a correta ?

Pretende-se enfatizar a presença dos envolvidos inclusive do interlocutor:

- Até o nosso encontro no dia tal com a fulana, vocês, e eu.
- Até o nosso encontro no dia tal, comigo, a fulana, e vocês.
- e outras combinações...

Quais formas são corretas ?

Comment: O teu título podia ser mais claro. Eu li e pensei, " 'encontro comigo', claro; 'encontro com eu' é um disparate. Mas depois, nenhuma das tuas frases me choca. Mas não sei elas serão aceitáveis; se não quisesse correr riscos, duplicaria a preposição: "encontro com vocês, a fulana e comigo" ou "encontro comigo, com a fulana e vocês". Ou reformulava: "encontro, em que estavam/participaram vocês, a fulana e eu".

Comment: @Jacinto Editei. Acha que está melhor ?

Answer (score 3):

O pronome "**eu**" deve aparecer após preposições em sua [forma preposicional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepositional_pronoun) "**mim**". Ou seja, usa-se "*para mim/de mim/sem mim*" em vez de "*para eu/de eu/sem eu*" ([exceto antes de orações subordinadas](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/morf/morf45.php)).

O mais certo seria usar "**mim**" quando a primeira pessoa aparece em posições não-inicial, ou usar a contração **comigo** quando a primeira pessoa aparece na posição inicial:

- "*[...] com a fulana, vocês, e mim.*"
- "*[...] com a fulana, mim, e vocês.*"
- "*[...] comigo, a fulana, e você.*"

Outra alternativa é simplesmente repetir a preposição em cada item da coordenação, obrigando o uso da contração e evitando ambiguidades:

- "*[...] comigo, com a fulana, e com você.*"

Comment: Não discuto se está certo ou errado, mas tanto "com a fulana, vocês, e mim" quanto "com a fulana, mim e vocês" soa muito estranho aos meus ouvidos.  Mesmo porque, "vocês" não é um pronome oblíquo.

Comment: @Centaurus. "Você" é um pronome não declinante e pode ser usado sem problemas após uma preposição; mas se desejar substituí-lo por um pronome oblíquo, há também "com a fulana, vós e mim". Mas ainda prefiro a construção em que se repete as preposições: "*com a fulana, comigo e convosco/com vocês*".

Comment: Entendo.  Eu me referi ao português falado.  Muitas vezes não uso determinada construção porque soa estranha, pedante ou até mesmo errada, embora seja a forma correta.   Se eu estiver no meio da rua e for roubado por alguém, eu poderia gritar "pega ele, pega ele" mas jamais gritaria "peguem-no, peguem-no".

Comment: Em português europeu esses "mim" também são dissonantes. Nisso eu concordo com o @Centaurus. E o mesmo para os outros: mim, ti, nos, vos. Nunca diria "Até o nosso encontro (...) com a fulana, vocês, e mim/ti/nos/vos.", diria ou «com a fulana, vocês, e eu/tu/nós/vós/vocês» ou «com a fulana e [vocês ou convosco] e comigo/contigo/connosco/convosco».

Comment: Acho que o cerne do meu desconforto é que se por um lado sim, o "com" **tem** de levar pronome preposicional (que se funde): comigo, contigo, com ele, connosco, convosco, com vocês, com eles. Mas por outro a frase não tem um "com" (diretamente) antes do eu/mim, então não soa _nada_ bem com mim. Acho até que me é menos dissonante «vais-te encontrar com eu e fulana» do que «vais-te encontrar com fulana e mim». Será que isto é simplesmente um caso de divergência entre o "uso comum" e a norma gramatical?