# É correto dizer "fulano e com eu", ou tem de ser "fulano e comigo"?

Tags: pronomes-oblíquos

O certo é falar "fulano e com eu?" ou "fulano e comigo?"

Vejo diversas pessoas que, ao eu falar "e com eu", questionam "comigo ?", o que me gera desconforto.

A minha dúvida é se ambas estão corretas, ou se o certo é apenas "comigo"?

Comment: Você poderia dar um exemplo? E Bem-vindo ao Portuguese StackExchange, Marcio Pires!

Comment: A pregunta carece de clareza.

Answer (score 4):

> O certo é falar "e com eu?" ou "comigo?"

Se você pergunta o que é "certo", então deve se referir à norma culta e, nesse caso, não há dúvida: apenas "comigo".

Quando o pronome da primeira pessoa é objeto ou complemento precedido de preposição, usa-se "mim" — e quando a preposição é "com", ela é contraída com o pronome: "comigo".

Alguns exemplos com a preposição em destaque:

- Ela confia **em** mim.
- Ele deu o livro **para** mim.
- **Sem** mim eles nunca teriam conseguido.
- Pode contar comigo (**com**+mim).

Em nenhum deles se poderia usar "eu" no lugar de "mim" na norma culta.

Acho que vale mencionar: uma [pergunta relacionada](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/4610/2764) no site; o caso do "[para eu](https://www.todamateria.com.br/eu-e-mim/)"; e um [artigo interessante](https://veja.abril.com.br/coluna/sobre-palavras/por-que-com-mim-virou-comigo/) sobre a etimologia de "comigo".

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142987/discussion-on-answer-by-stafusa-e-correto-dizer-fulano-e-com-eu-ou-tem-de-ser); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

No dia-a-dia, utilizamos "fulano e comigo".
Nunca ouvi ninguém falando "fulano e com eu". Dei uma rápida pesquisa no Google e me parece que é correto sim, mas não é falado no cotidiano (deve ser por isso que estão te corrigindo. Se eu mesma não tivesse pesquisado, teria dito que estava errado. Para nós, soa muito estranho).
Na dúvida, você pode escolher dizer "eu e fulano." ou "comigo e fulano" que ambos estarão certos e são usados no dia-a-dia

Comment: "Fulano e comigo" ?   Seria uma frase do tipo "Ela saiu com fulano e comigo" ?   Neste caso não haveria nada de errado.

Comment: Me parece que "comigo e fulano" teria que ser "comigo e com fulano".